# Azure Cognitive search, Lucene, Full words to return abbreviated results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way in azure cognitive search to match abbreviations as well?

For example, on our dataset we have

```
5510 S Rice Ave

5510 ST something something
```

We are doing a lucene search, we try to use fuzzy search with the following parameters:

```
&search=5510 STR~
&top=100
&zipcode=77081
&query-type=full
&search-fields=Address
```

However, how come with the query above we get

`5510 ST something something`

but not

`5510 S Rice Ave`??

shouldn't `5510 S` in `5510 S Rice Ave` also be part of the fuzzy search for `&search=5510 STR~`?

What should our query look like so it includes 5510 S?

Also, S there is supposed to be an abbreviation for "SOUTH" What should the query look like so that anyone searching for

`5510 SOUTH`

Will also get

`5510 S Rice`?

Answer (score 1):

1. It should. Unless your `zipcode` filter is not satisfied for `5510 S Rice Ave`, the search query WILL return both results. I have just tested with this sample data and confirmed that it works.
2. [Synonym maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms). You need to create a synonym map.

```
POST /synonymmaps?api-version=<api-version>
{
    "name": "acronyms",
    "format": "solr",
    "synonyms": "
        S, South, Southern\n
        N, North, Northern\n"
        W, West, Western\n"
        E, East, Eastern\n"
        NE, NorthEast, NorthEastern\n"
        SW, SouthWest, SouthWestern\n"
}
```

Then, you have to enable the synonym map for your field

```
POST /indexes?api-version=<api-version>
{
    "name":"<index-name>",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"name",
            "type":"Edm.String",
            "searchable":true,
            "synonymMaps":[
            "acronyms"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you do this, your query with abbreviations will automatically get results for the full thing and vice versa. You are allowed up to 20 synonym maps per resource and will be shared across indexes.

Comment: appreciate the answer. Currently we are checking as to what would the other cause of the errors are, but the suggestion to use synonyms is interestign and we wil look into that